# Tmux history limit not working with putty

Tags: tmux

I use putty to connect to my remote servers and I use tmux on it.

I tried adding this to my tmux.conf:

```
set -g history-limit 150000
```

Even after rebooting the server and logging back again, it does not change how much I can scrollback.

Any ideas? I'm using ubuntu 18.04 and tmux 2.6 I used to be able to scrollback a lot with putty

Comment: Have you tried going to PuTTY settings > Window > Lines of scrollback and changing the amount of lines to 150000 too?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work

Comment: Maybe you gotta increase the buffer size then

Comment: where? Remember this only happened after starting to use tmux. Never had a issue with putty before

Comment: Try running `tmux new-session` and then `tmux show-options -g`. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812326/cant-increase-scrollback-buffer-size-in-tmux)